# Laravel: Look for object in multiple different tables

Tags: laravel

I have 4 different tables in a Laravel app: one of all appointments and then three which have the various types of appointments (i.e. OnlineAppointments, PhysicalAppointments, OffsiteAppointments) and have foreign keys to the Appointments table. Now I am trying to figure out how to find the related appointment (in its appointment type table) using the id of the appointment.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is look for the appointment on all 3 "appointment type" tables but I am not sure what the syntax in the controller is. What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
$appointment = PhysicalAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id) ||

                       OnlineAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id) ||

                       OffsiteAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id)

                       ->findOrFail();
```

But this does not work. The || are meant to represent "OR". Just wondering what the correct syntax is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
$appointment = PhysicalAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id)->first();
if(!$appointment) {
   $appointment = OnlineAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id)->first();
    if (!$appointment) {
      $appointment = OffsiteAppointments::where('appointment_id', $request->appointment_id)->first();
    }
}
echo($appointment);
```